# How to add indentation for TextView android

Tags: android, layout, textview

How to add indentation for `TextView` android?

[image: Screen]

1) How to find number a string in `TextView`?
2) How to add this line indent, say '\t'?

Comment: what did you try to do?

Comment: Used LeadingMarginSpan2, but it generally turns out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to create multiple `TextView` in a vertical linear layout.
Then, you could use the `paddingLeft` or `layout_marginLeft` to indent your text.

Another possibility could be using a `WebView`, set your text in HTML and put it into the `WebView`

Comment: The thing is, I do not know what the original text that you want to throw indented and which is not indented.

Comment: I'm not asking you to calculate the indentation, as I myself can do. I just need to figure out how to add a specific line of the symbol "\t"

Comment: Using a `TextView`, you can't do this : `myTextView.setText("\tThis is an indented text");` ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to say that you want to add \t when a new poin comes? 
For eg:
<\t>1. xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
<\t>2.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxx

Comment: not,
This is, String=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxSxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxSxxxxxxxxxxxxxxSxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxSxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx;
When I add text in TextView. The displays are different.On a single display, the text will be from 5 lines, on the other 10. I have just in each row add space. How to do it?